# Sum of series $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{e^{\beta n}+1}$ with $\beta >0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, statistical-mechanics

I'm wondering if there exists a closed form or at least some asymptotic expansion in the limit $\beta \rightarrow \infty$ for the sum of the series 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{e^{\beta n}+1}$$
with $\beta >0$.

$1/(e^{\beta n}+1)$ is the Fermi distribution $1/(e^{\beta (\epsilon_n-\mu)}+1)$ with chemical potential $\mu=0$ and energy $\epsilon_n=n$.

Comment: Have you tried Wolframalpha? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F(a%5En+%2B+1)
Not a very nice expression tho :(
You could use the fact that $1/(e^{\beta n} +1) \approx e^{-\beta n}$ and then sum it as a geometric series.

Comment: No, I hadn't tried. Thank you